# How to make XmlSerializer.Deserialize handle DefaultAttribute properly?

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlserializer

There seems to be a bug / inconsistency in the Microsoft XmlSerializer: If you have a property marked with a `System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue` attribute, this does not get serialized. Fair enough - this could be seen as an expected behavior.

The problem is the same attribute is not respected when deserializing. The code below illustrates the issue.

Question is how could I bypass this? I have potentially hundreds of business classes with default values used in the UI tier (Views), so default value initialization in constructor is not an option. It has to be something generic. I could create a completely new default attribute, but it seems like duplicate work. Do you see a way to override the XmlSerializer behavior or should I use just another serializer that does the job better?

The example code:

```
public class DefaultValueTestClass
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(10000)]
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void SimpleDefaultValueTest()
{
    // Create object and set the property value TO THE DEFAULT
    var before = new DefaultValueTestClass();
    before.Foo = 10000;
    // Serialize => xml
    var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(DefaultValueTestClass));
    string xml;
    using (var stream = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, before);
        xml = stream.ToString();
    }

    // Deserialize the same object
    DefaultValueTestClass after;
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StringReader(xml))
    {
        after = (DefaultValueTestClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    // before.Foo = 10000
    // after.Foo = 0
    Assert.AreEqual(before.Foo, after.Foo);
}
```

Comment: I guess you can through reflection, upon deserialization, grab all the properties of your class and its superclasses with DefaultValue attribute, for each of them grab the value, convert it to the correct type, and still through reflection, call the setter method of the property on your deserialized object, with the grabbed value as argument

Comment: @jbl Yes, this is what I do in the UI tier. But I cannot do it after the XmlSerializer.Deserialize because I do not know whether Foo=0 because it was not serialized or because it was set by the user as 0. Going this way, I would need to plug into the serializer before the Deserialization happens. And do not know how (except in contructor, which I do not want to do because of large amount of classes).

Comment: Maybe this can be done with some Dynamic Proxies which would implement the IXmlSerializable interface in place of your classes. I must confess it's just random thoughts though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *your job* to implement the defaults; `[DefaultValue]` merely says "this is the default, you don't need to worry about this" - it doesn't *apply* it. This applies not just to `XmlSerializer`, but to the core `System.ComponentModel` API to which `[DefaultValue]` belongs (which drives things like the bold / not-bold in `PropertyGrid`, etc)

Basically:

```
public class DefaultValueTestClass
{
    public DefaultValueTestClass()
    {
        Foo = 10000;
    }
    [DefaultValue(10000)]
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

will work in the way you expect. If you want it to serialize whether or not it is that particular value, then the correct implementations is:

```
public class DefaultValueTestClass
{
    public DefaultValueTestClass()
    {
        Foo = 10000;
    }
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to preserve the `[DefaultValue]`, but want it to always serialize, then:

```
public class DefaultValueTestClass
{
    [DefaultValue(10000)]
    public int Foo { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public bool ShouldSerializeFoo() { return true; }
}
```

Where `ShouldSerialize*` is another pattern from `System.ComponentModel` that is recognised by several serializers.

---

And here's some UI code to show that `XmlSerializer` is actually doing exactly the same things that the UI code (built on `System.ComponentModel`) has always done:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
static class Program
{
    [System.STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        using (var form = new Form())
        using (var grid = new PropertyGrid())
        {
            grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            var obj = new DefaultValueTestClass
            {   // TODO - try with other numbers to
                // see bold / not bold
                Foo = 10000
            };
            // note in the grid the value is shown not-bold; that is
            // because System.ComponentModel is saying
            // "this property doesn't need to be serialized"
            // - or to show it more explicitly:
            var prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj)["Foo"];
            bool shouldSerialize = prop.ShouldSerializeValue(obj);
            // ^^^ false, because of the DefaultValueAttribute
            form.Text = shouldSerialize.ToString(); // win title

            grid.SelectedObject = obj;
            form.Controls.Add(grid);
            Application.Run(form);            
        }
    }
}

public class DefaultValueTestClass
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(10000)]
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As I said above: "I have potentially hundreds of business classes with default values used in the UI tier (Views), so default value initialization in constructor is not an option." I am using the attribute in the UI like the property-grids etc. did in the old WinForms era.

Comment: @Ope did you see the third option I edited at the bottom, which doesn't use this? Also : `XmlSerializer` uses exactly the same rules as `PropertyGrid` etc does in WinForms: so (and I don't mean this disparagingly - simply a clear statement of what the current state is) what you are *actually* saying there is "I've been using it incorrectly for ages, but now it *matters* that I've been using it incorrectly" - that isn't really `XmlSerializer`'s fault. Hopefully, the `ShouldSerialize*` should be enough to get you working.

Comment: @Ope I'll edit in an illustration of the UI code working in exactly the same way

Comment: OK, I do stand corrected: This is then by design. It is not so clear from DefaultValueAttribute documentation, but PropertyDescriptor.ShouldSerializeValue says the intention pretty clearly. For my case, what then makes most sense is to create a new attribute e.g. UserDefault because that is quite simple refactoring even if it touches a lot of classes - there is less chance for mistakes in the future objects than with ShouldSerializeFoo(). It also better shows the intent: This is the default value when the user (not constructor) creates a new object. But thanks!